# Create unique id per iteration, then specify behavior when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an `html.erb` file where I'm creating a new row as I iterate over a collection. I need to be able to dynamically create an `id` per row, and then be able to specify that `id` in my `.js` file so that I can show/hide some of its contents when clicked.

```
#foo.html.erb file
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Group Name </th>
      <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th> Count </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @groups.each do |group_name, count_for_group| %> 
      <tr id="unique_id"> #create unique id here
        <td> <%= group_name %> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> <%= count_for_group %> </td> #this should be hidden. If the row this data belongs to is clicked, then show it. If clicked again, then hide it.
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And then I need to be able to show/hide that group's `count` when clicked, but I don't know how to find an id that was dynamically created:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/test.js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#dynamic_group_id").on(“click”, function(e){ #somehow be able to specify the dynamically created id
    #show/hide contents
  });
});
```

Comment: Generate `class` instead of `id` then use `event delegation` to hook up the events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are abusing element IDs. Use IDs for truly unique identifiers.

For everything else there are other selectors - the most commonly used are classes.

```js
$(".group").on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('.hide-me').toggle();
});

console.log($(".group"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Group Name</th>
      <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="group">
      <td>The Beatles</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="hide-me">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="group">
      <td>The Rolling Stones</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="hide-me">4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```